# AndroidManifest support only devices with 3G

Tags: android, android-manifest

Recently I was asked question if there is a way to make app avaiable to devices with support for 3G networks with AndroidManifest.xml. The only thing that came in mind at that time is to use:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

But I'm sure that solution gives me more that desired result because this feature also allows devices that are supporting only 2G.

Is there a better way to achive desired result of supporting only 3G devices?

Comment: Was that an interview question? Why the need to filter out 3G devices, that is carrier dependent. Not the app.

Comment: @t0mm13b I've edited a question to make it more clear. This wasn't interview question. It was asked by PM from client's side.

Comment: Like as stated, the telephony layer is responsible for selecting the best signal based on triangulation, be it, LTE/4G/3G/HSPA etc. and depends on the carrier.

Comment: Only make the app available for devices with 3G when uploading it to Google Play. Of course this require you to select the devices manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot filter based on connectivity type in the manifest, but once you have access to the network state permission, you can check the network type in your code and restrict usage if the user is not on 3G or better.

Comment: I know that :) But I look for solution related with AndroidManifest only.

Comment: I was just clarifying with the beginning of my answer - unfortunately that's not possible.